# Why doesn't my toString() method properly override the toString() method in its superclass?

Tags: java, overriding, subclass, tostring

I'm writing a subclass with a `toString()` method which I would like to be printed when items of that subclass are read in an arraylist, however it just prints the `toString()` of the superclass when an item of that type is added to an arraylist. Here is the code for the subclass:

```
package shop;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class MultiBuyProduct extends Product{
private int minDiscountedQuantity;
private int discountPercent;

public MultiBuyProduct(String name, double price, int quantity, int minDiscountedQuantity, int discountPercent) {
    super(name, price, quantity);
    this.minDiscountedQuantity = minDiscountedQuantity;
    this.discountPercent = discountPercent;
}

    //getters and setters

    public double getTotalPrice() {
        if (getQuantity() >= getMinDiscountedQuantity()) {
            double total = getPrice() * getQuantity();
            double discountedTotal = total - ((discountPercent/100) * total); 
            return discountedTotal;
        }
        return getPrice() * getQuantity();
    }

    public double discount() {
        double total = getPrice() * getQuantity();
        double discount = (discountPercent/100) * total;
        return discount;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
        return String.format("%s,\n%20s%5.2f)", super.toString(), format.format(getTotalPrice()), "(Multibuy Discount: GBP ", discount());

    }
}
```

This is the toString in the superclass `Products`

```
public String toString() {
    DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
    return String.format("%3d * GBP %5s  %-20s= GBP %7s", quantity, format.format(price), 
                        name, format.format(getTotalPrice()));

}
```

I have this here are parts of the class which contains the main method, `ShoppingCart`:

```
public class ShoppingCart {
private ArrayList<Product> cart;

    public ShoppingCart() {
        cart = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        double total = 0;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (Product p : cart) {
            sb.append(p.toString()).append("\n");
            total += p.getTotalPrice();
        }
        sb.append(String.format("%48s \n%40s%8.2f", "------------", "TOTAL GBP", total));
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ShoppingCart newCart = new ShoppingCart();

        Product apple, milk, caulk, ice, snakes;
        MultiBuyProduct snakesMulti;
        apple = new Product("Apples (4 pack)", 1.20, 1);
        milk = new Product("Milk (1l)", 0.75, 1);
        caulk = new Product("Caulk (1l)", 6.84, 1);
        ice = new Product("Ice (1kg)", 4.30, 1);
        snakes = new Product("Snake (5m)", 32.0, 1);
        snakesMulti = new MultiBuyProduct("Snakes", 30.0, 12, 3, 20);

        newCart.add(apple);
        newCart.add(apple);
        newCart.add(apple);
        newCart.add(caulk);
        newCart.add(milk);
        newCart.add(milk);
        newCart.add(snakes);
        newCart.add(ice);
        newCart.add(ice);
        newCart.add(snakesMulti);


        System.out.println(newCart);


    }
```

which prints:

```
  3 * GBP  1.20  Apples (4 pack)     = GBP    3.60
  1 * GBP  6.84  Caulk (1l)          = GBP    6.84
  2 * GBP   .75  Milk (1l)           = GBP    1.50
  1 * GBP 32.00  Snake (5m)          = GBP   32.00
  2 * GBP  4.30  Ice (1kg)           = GBP    8.60
 12 * GBP 30.00  Snakes              = GBP  360.00
                                    ------------ 
                               TOTAL GBP  412.54
```

but it should print:

```
  3 * GBP  1.20  Apples (4 pack)     = GBP    3.60
  1 * GBP  6.84  Caulk (1l)          = GBP    6.84
  2 * GBP   .75  Milk (1l)           = GBP    1.50
  1 * GBP 32.00  Snake (5m)          = GBP   32.00
  2 * GBP  4.30  Ice (1kg)           = GBP    8.60
 12 * GBP 30.00  Snakes              = GBP  288.00
       (Multibuy Discount: GBP 72.00
                                    ------------ 
                               TOTAL GBP  340.54
```

Would I need a main method in `MultiBuyProduct` itself, or can I use the one in `ShoppingCart`? I can provide more code for context if it is needed.

Edit: I have found the source of the problem. In `ShoppingCart.add()` I check through the item, and if it is not already in the arraylist, it creates a copy of the item and adds it to the arraylist:

```
public void add(Product p) {
    if (cart.size() > 0) {
        for (Product i : cart) {
            if (i.getName().equals(p.getName()) 
                && i.getPrice() == p.getPrice()) {

                i.setQuantity(i.getQuantity() + p.getQuantity());
                return;
            }
        } 
        cart.add(new Product(p)); //this is done because if it were just cart.add(p), it would change the product being assigned as well as the product in the arraylist
    } else {
        cart.add(new Product(p));
    }
}
```

`Product (p)` is defined in `Product` as

```
public Product(Product p) {
    this.name = p.name;
    this.price = p.price;
    this.quantity = p.quantity;

}
```

Which means that any items of type `MultiBuyProduct` lose their `minDiscountedQuantity` and `discountPercent` values. I am unsure how to fix this, as I cannot extend `public Product(Product p)` to `MultiBuyProduct`

Comment: `System.out.println(newCart);` invokes the `toString` of `newCart`, which is a `ShoppingCart` - you haven't posted that. So I can only assume it never invokes the `toString()` of your `MultiBuyProduct`

Comment: I've updated with my other `toString()` methods. I believe in `ShoppingCart` it adds each item of type `Product` to the `toString()` and since `MultiBuyProduct` is a subclass of `Product`, this should add multibuyproducts to the `toString()` as well, right? I've also shown how ShoppingCart is constructed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some example code. Please see if this is what is your application trying to do (is this the behavior)?

The example has an `Animal` class. The `Dog` class *extends* `Animal`. Both have the `java.lang.Object`'s `toString` method overridden.

```
class Animal {

    private String name;

    public Animal(String s) {
        name = s;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Animal name: " + name;
    }
}

class Dog extends Animal {

    private String name;

    public Dog(String s) {
        super(s);
        name = s;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Dog Name: " + name + ", " + super.toString();
    }
}


Public class TestingInheritance {
    public static void main(String [] args) {

        Animal d0 = new Animal("just animal");  
        Animal d1 = new Dog("mutt");
        Dog d2 = new Dog("pup");

        System.out.println(d0);
        System.out.println(d1);
        System.out.println(d2);
        System.out.println("");

        List<Animal>  anims = Arrays.asList(d0, d1, d2);
        for (Animal a : anims) {
            System.out.println(a.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

The Output:

```
Animal name: just animal
Dog Name: mutt, Animal name: mutt
Dog Name: pup, Animal name: pup

Animal name: just animal
Dog Name: mutt, Animal name: mutt
Dog Name: pup, Animal name: pup
```

Comment: Thank you, apart from some formatting errors in the `toString()`, my `MultiBuyProduct` class was fine, the problem lies in how items are added to the arraylist in `ShoppingCart`, I elaborated in my most recent edit.

Comment: _the problem lies in how items are added to the arraylist in ShoppingCart_ Do you know what the problem is _and_ did you find the solution?

Comment: As I said, I elaborate in the main question. The `ShoppingCart.add()` method creates a copy of the item to add to the arraylist so that the original item doesn't get edited. The problem is that the copy only contains the variables of `Product` and doesn't contain any from `MultiBuyProduct`, so when a `MultiBuyProduct` is passed through `ShoppingCart.add()`, it loses its variables. I don't know how to fix this

Comment: The `Product` has multiple constructors?

Comment: Yes, it has one to create an initial item, and one to create a copy of that item to be added into the arraylist

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184787/discussion-between-prasad-and-kotsoteka).